# Selenium/VBA/Javascript: Trigger Mouse Event

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, selenium, webdriver

I have some Webdriver (java) code that I am looking to translate to VBA. The code is as follows:

```
    WebElement pos1 = LiloTest.driver.findElement(By.id("autoAssocitionForm:categoryDetailCombinationId:23"));

    JavascriptLibrary jsLib = new JavascriptLibrary(); 

    jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(LiloTest.driver,"triggerMouseEventAt", pos1,"click", "0,0");
```

I am trying to run the equivalent in VBA, utilizing the Selenium type library, but I am not quite sure how to make it work. I have tried using the "ExecuteScript" method, but have not had much luck. Part of the problem is that I can't see any javascript when looking at the page source, etc., for the element in question.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out:

```
 JsTest = "document.getElementById('autoAssocitionForm:categoryDetailCombinationId:23').checked = true;"

 Set Pos = bot.FindElementById("autoAssocitionForm:categoryDetailCombinationId:23")

 Pos.ExecuteScript (JsTest)
```